# strange values when input (18,18) in Grid traveler problem using Memoization in c

Tags: c

I'm learning dynamic programming and I've just started with some simple problems. I'm doing a grid traveler problem where you start in the top-left corner of a grid and you can only move right or down. You need to return the amount of unique paths to get from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner of the grid.

I'm getting some strange return values when I try (18,18). it goes to -> -1961361076 instead of 2333606220

Can anyone see something wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int grid(int row,int col,int a,int arr[][a]){

    if(arr[row][col]!=-1){return arr[row][col];}
    arr[row][col]=grid(row-1,col,a,arr)+grid(row,col-1,a,arr);
    return arr[row][col];
}

int main()
{
int row=18,col=18;
int arr[row][col];
for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        if(i==0 || j==0){
            arr[i][j]=1;
            }
        else{
            arr[i][j]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
int a=col;
printf("%d",grid(row-1,col-1,a,arr));
}
```

Comment: Oh that's horrible code. And there's no kind of bounds-checking whatever which leads to you going out of bounds of the arrays and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It also looks very much like you're using some kind of "competition" or "judge" site to learn C. No matter what you've heard, such sites are ***not*** any kind of learning or teaching resource, quite the opposite. If you want to learn C then invest in good books. If you want to become a good programmer then stay in school and take computer-science classes and learn multiple languages.

Comment: I assume you're using a 32-bit computer. In 2's complement, 32-bit computers, the maximum value for an `int` is "`2^31 - 1`" or `2147483647` which is less than the result you expected.

Comment: @arun – You say _you start in the top-left corner of a grid and you can only move left or down._ For me this means you can only move down.

Comment: @armali-oh, I'm sorry it's actually right and down.

Comment: You have no comments, your variables are poorly named. Imagine coming back to that code after a day or a few weeks...

Comment: Just use `long long` (and the corresponding `"%lld"`) instead of `int`.